# Set Input Directory Path for ArcMap Geoprocessing Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arctoolbox

How do I set the input file directory in a arcmap geoprocessing tool?

I want to be able to input a file from a specific directory without having to browse for the directory every time I want to run a geoprocessing tool.[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to use data located in the same file, you must set this file as current workspace in ArcMap. In the Menu, go to Geoprocessing > Environment, Expand Workspace > select the file you want to use as a workspace. The workspace can also be a geodatabase. See [Current Workspace (Environment setting)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/current-workspace.htm) for more details about the current workspace and how to customize it.

This allows you to type only the basename of the dataset (e.g.: points.shp). The complete path to the data will be updated when you've finished typing (and click elsewhere). As @artwork mentions, if you click the browse button to select a dataset, you will land in the last browsed folder.

Comment: This option does not seem to work.  It only remembers the last directory.  If last directory is different the current workspace it chooses last directory.

Answer (score 1):

To set home directory, select Catalog Option button (in ArcMap)>Home Folder and browse for new home folder.  Note for this update to take place you will have to close and re-open the application.  Finally, open desired tool click parameter browse folder icon, and click the "Go To Home Folder" button and it will re-direct to the defined home directory.  It seems that the "Go To Home Folder" button is only available in geoprocessing tools when opened within ArcMap.

See [Working with the Home folder and default geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/working-with-the-home-folder-and-default-geodatabase.htm)

Comment: Yes, but if I want to set a different directory for another geoprocessing tool. It looks like the Home folder  will be applied to all the tools. I want to be able to set different directories for other geoprocessing tool.

Comment: I'm afraid that functionality does not exist, you could propose it here https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas

Comment: Is there a way a tool can recoginze the current workpsace setting  from a python script like:  arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Directory/somefolder"

Comment: Yes, but that sounds like a new question.